Travel to Ireland for Bulgarian D-type visa holder
My friend (an Indian) is studying medicine in Bulgaria. He is on a D-Type prolonged residence visa issued by Bulgaria. Can he travel to Ireland by air for a visit without applying for a visa, or is he entitled for a visa on arrival in Ireland?

Your friend must apply for a visa in advance. Whether a visa is required to visit Ireland depends on the traveler's nationality or (for refugees) the country that issued them a travel document. Other than family members of EU citizens, all Indian nationals require a visa.

For context, this is because while the Republic of Ireland is in the EU, they are not in the Schengen Area, so Schengen visas are not valid there.

For reference see Irish Immigration and related question
